# GRUB menu lost in win 8 dual boot configuration after hard drive swap

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Packard Bell imedia S2185 set to dual boot Win 8\ **Ubuntu 14.04** and was using it to work on an embedded linux deployment.

I had an issue on another PC and swapped over the hard-drives to see if the fail carried.

After putting back in the original hard-drive, everything seemed ok but at some point after a re-boot, (can't recall when exactly), the grub menu disappeared.  I suspect windows noticed the hard-drive swap and 'healed' the boot manager

Most of my work is in the Ubuntu partition, plus I can no longer use Ubuntu which is the primary use of the PC.

How can I boot into the Ubuntu partition or get the grub menu back?

**Windows was NOT reinstalled**  This is a separate issue related to swapping hard-drives.

Comment: This link has probably got the answer you're looking for: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Boot-Repair as in answer below will work only if you boot in same boot mode. Direct link to Boot-Repair. You can use Ubuntu installer and add Boot-Repair to it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Thanks simernes, your link worked.  The new grub is a bit weird http://imgur.com/blZ8uHb but i am back up and running which is the main thing

Comment: @simernes: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before and I always follow this site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

But here's a copy-paste of what you need to do:

#### Short story:

Boot Ubuntu using Live CD or USB and run `sudo grub-install /dev/XXX` replacing XXX with the device you installed Ubuntu on, for example `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

#### Long story:

Boot up Ubuntu using a Live CD or USB.

Open a terminal. As of Ubuntu 11.10 and 11.04, this can be done by opening the Unity Dash (you can click the Ubuntu logo in the top panel or use the Windows key on your keyboard) and typing in "Terminal", and clicking what comes up. On earlier versions, you can achieve this by going to <kbd>Applications</kbd>→<kbd>Accessories</kbd>→<kbd>Terminal</kbd>. Alternately use the Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

For full details on using terminal to fix grub on hard drive from Live Installer DVD or Flash: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal

```
You are then presented with a standard bash prompt, type - this only works to reinstall to MBR of a working system: 

sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

where XXX is the device of your Ubuntu install. (E.g.: `grub-install /dev/sdb`). **Hint**: You can also use `/dev/disk/by-label/` if the partition you installed on has a label. You can determine the `/dev` node for such a device by running:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

This will give the output of something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 data -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 data2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 fat -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 home -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 root -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 swap -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 windows -> ../../sdb1
```

You can also use `gparted --list` if you do not see the `/dev/disk/by-label`:

$ sudo parted --list

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10TPVT-00U (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 3      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4
```

From here, find only the drive name, ignore the partition number, that is, for partitions labelled `root`, `data2`, `fat`, `home` and `swap` it's all still just `sda`. This is due to the fact that GRUB is installed in the MBR of the drive, and not on a partition.

Trouble? If other things are messed up, e.g. if you have deleted the partition from where Grub was previously installed, grub-install may return an error message such as `cannot find a device for /... (is /dev mounted?)`. You may have to do `grub-install` a bit differently. Refer to the handy guide on fixing a broken system

Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)